# how make an alert in same page with data entered in form present using flask regarding the data submitted

Tags: javascript, html, flask, jinja2, pageload

Flask Code (app.py)

```
from flask import Flask, redirect,render_template,  url_for, request
app = Flask(__name__)
sum = ""
@app.route('/')
def prin():
    return render_template('index.html',v = sum)

@app.route('/res', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def calculate():
    S = int(request.form['sender'])
    R = int(request.form['receiver'])
    globals()['sum'] = S+R
    return redirect(url_for('prin'))
if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug = True)
```

HTML Page (index.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var ans = '{{v}}'
        if (ans !== "") {
            window.alert(ans)
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="trans">
        <form action="http://127.0.0.1:5000/res" onsubmit="return (validate());" method="POST">
        <label for="sender">Sender Id</label>
        <input type="number" name="sender" id="Sender" placeholder="Enter Sender Id">
        <br>
        <label for="receiver">Receiver Id</label>
        <input type="number"  name="receiver" id="Receiver" placeholder="Enter Receiver Id">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**In the website the alert is coming with empty or loading background**
[Data Entered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdRLl.jpg)
[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhYBE.jpg)

**But how Can i get the background to make form visible with the values submitted in it along with the alert?**
(like shown in figure)
[Required Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xt3PM.jpg)

Comment: Why do you need flask for this?. You could everything in JS itself. If you want stop reload you need to prevent default and make xhr request and then alert it.

Comment: yes we could do in JS, but i need it as a sub module in my flask Project. As it need to some data processing in flask(back-end) and return output as an alert

Comment: you could use some ajax that calls a flask function, and show alert with its output?

Comment: if possible can send that ajax code which would do my job, as i don't have basics about ajax @gittert